# Trying to make a check palindrome function

Tags: python

```
###The file has a bunch of words that are in a line. I want to be able to itirate through each word in the list and then access each letter in the word but I am not able to itirate through different first word. Please help with check_palindrome###
```

---

The check palindrome function is the one i need help with. I have been able to check the palindrome correctly for the first item in the list but it doesnt work for the other words because it wont get past the first word.

```
def check_palindrome(string):
n = 0
i = len(string[n]) - 1
first = ''
while n < len(string) - 1:
    while i >= 0:
        first += string[n][i]
        i -= 1
    print(string[n], first)
    if first == string[n]:
        print(string[n], 'is a palindrome')
    else:
        print(string[n], 'is not a palindrome')
    n += 1

def load_words(file_name):
file = open(file_name)
string = []
for words in file:
    words = words.lower()
    string.append(words.strip())
return string

if __name__ == '__main__':
file_name = input('What file shoulf we check for palindrome? ')
check_palindrome(load_words(file_name))
```

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: does the check palindrome function check whether a string is a palindrome or not? If yes it should return Bool?

Comment: Please indent the `check_palindrome` function, and your `__main__` entry correctly. Also, you have made `string` a list, not a string. Work on ensuring you have loaded the file into a single string first.

Comment: One more easy way to check if a string is palindrome is `string == string[::-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code is you have to define `first = ''` and `i = len(string[n]) - 1` inside the first while loop. Because each time you are checking for a new word.
And your code will not check for last word. You have to change this `while n < len(string) - 1` to this `while n < len(string)`.

Change your while loop as below.

```
while n < len(string):
    first = ''
    i = len(string[n]) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        first += string[n][i]
        i -= 1
    print(string[n], first)
    if first == string[n]:
        print(string[n], 'is a palindrome')
    else:
        print(string[n], 'is not a palindrome')
    n += 1
```

Simplified version of your program.

```
def check_palindrome(words):
    for word in words:
        print(word, 'is a palindrome') if word == word[::-1] else print(word, 'is not a palindrome')

def load_words(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fp:
        return [line.strip().lower() for line in fp if line.strip()]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_name = input('What file shoulf we check for palindrome? ')
    check_palindrome(load_words(file_name))
```